# Complex data relationships migration using DX

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I need to migrate complicated data relationships between several organization using DX. For example, 10 accounts with 100 related contacts with 1000 related opportunities.

I have tried to combine a plan

```
[
    {
        "sobject": "Opportunity",
        "saveRefs": true,
        "resolveRefs": false,
        "files": [
            "Opportunitys.json"
        ]
    },
    {
        "sobject": "Contact",
        "saveRefs": false,
        "resolveRefs": true,
        "files": [
            "Contacts.json"
        ]
    ,
    {
        "sobject": "Account",
        "saveRefs": false,
        "resolveRefs": true,
        "files": [
            "Accounts.json"
        ]
    }
]
```

However, this doesn't work anyway because of limitation of 200 records which can be processed with " sfdx force:data:tree:import -p " command, so when I run this command I receive "LIMIT_EXCEEDED  The request can’t contain more than 200 records total." error.

Also, if I try to use data:soql:query and data:bulk:upsert it is not clear how should I select sample data I am interested in so that they are related. Is there any better option to migrate complex data relationships using SFDX?

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the 200 record limit by breaking your json files up into files that contain 200 records or less (ie Accounts1.json, Accounts2.json).  Then update your plan file with the list of files you split the data into.  You have to do this manually unfortunately.